# Button should be unselectable and only selectable if choosing a radio option

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the button at the bottom to be unselectable and only selectable when you select an age group radio button. I'm not sure why but I think the function 'EnableButton' is invalid since if I remove it, the bottom button becomes unselectable, so the other function 'DisableButton' must be correct.

Can someone help to explain the problem?

```js
var disablebutton = document.getElementById("to-enable"); // global variable
function DisableButton() { // disables 'to-enable' button
 disablebutton.disabled = true;
}

DisableButton(); // runs the disable button function

function EnableButton() { // function that enables button
 var ValidateAge = document.forms["registration-form"]["age"].value;
 if (ValidateAge != undefined) {
  disablebutton.disabled = false;
 }
}

EnableButton(); // runs the enable button function
```

```html
<form id="registration-form">
 <input type="text" name="forename"> Forename<br>
 <input type="text" name="surname"> Surname<br>
 <input type="text" name="email"> Email<br>
 <textarea name="address" rows="5" cols="40">Type your full address here...</textarea> Address<br><br>
    Which planets have you already seen through a telescope?<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="planets" value="none">None<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="planets" value="mercury">Mercury<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="planets" value="venus">Venus<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="planets" value="mars">Mars<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="planets" value="jupiter">Jupiter<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="planets" value="saturn">Saturn<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="planets" value="usanus">Uranus<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="planets" value="neptune">Neptune<br><br>
    What is your age group?<br>
    <input type="radio" name="age">Under 18<br>
    <input type="radio" name="age">18-30<br>
    <input type="radio" name="age">30-50<br>
    <input type="radio" name="age">50+<br><br>
    What country are you from?
    <select name="Country">
  <option value="not-selected">Not Selected</option>
  <option value="england">England</option>
  <option value="wales">Wales</option>
  <option value="scotland">Scotland</option>
  <option value="northern-ireland">Northern Ireland</option>
 </select>
    <br><br>
</form>

<button onClick="ResetForm()">Reset</button>
<button onClick="SubmitForm()" id="submit">Submit</button>
<button id="to-enable">Select an age group to activate this button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is both functions are runs immediately. So, the `radio` is not selected at that time. And hence it won't enable it.

You can use either `eventListener` on radio or an `interval`.

`eventListener` is prefered.

The code to do this is

```
 document.querySelectorAll('input[name=age]').forEach(x => x.addEventListener('change',EnableButton));
```

Comment: good suggestion but what can I type inside a logical operator to argue "if the 'input name - age' radio button has not been selected yet?"

Comment: the `EventListener` triggered on change. A change will happen only if you check the radio button. It can be checked but can't be unchecked

Comment: Try running it in browser and copy the error from console

Answer (score 0):

Add div on-click.

**HTML**

```
What is your age group?<br>

<div div onclick="EnableButton()" id="under18">  

<input type="radio" name="age">Under 18<br>  

</div>
<input type="radio" name="age">18-30<br>
<input type="radio" name="age">30-50<br>
<input type="radio" name="age">50+<br><br>
```

**JS**

```
function EnableButton() { // function that enables button
  disablebutton.disabled = false;
}
```

**EDIT**

You need a while loop:

**JS**

```
i = 2
function EnableButton() { // function that enables button
while (i<10) {
  disablebutton.disabled = false;
}}
```